# Unity: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{layoutlib}' is expected

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build

I build Unity project with upgrade Android Target API level from 30 to 31. After adding a new library, it became necessary to raise the Target API. Local build (on my Mac) build correctly, but build in TeamCity on builder is Failed with exeption:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{layoutlib}' is expected.:
>
> 19:36:04   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 141; columnNumber: 252; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{layoutlib}' is expected.
>
> 19:36:04     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
> more very long stack trace

I found the error description `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a` in google (is validate xml files), but i'm not understand where incorrect xml, and how to fix it. How can I find incorrect xml and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
Problem in JDK. Local JDK version 11.0, but on builder 1.8. For 31 API Level need JDK 11.0.

Comment: what is "bulder" ? did you mean builder ?

Comment: Builder is a local machine on which our company compiles solutions.