# Unity build does not work in Android 13 (api 33)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-build, android-13

When I got the build from the project, the game worked fine on all Androids. But the game crashes on Android 13! And it says that the program has stopped.

First, I said that the problem might be with the SDKs. I downloaded all the new SDKs, but the problem was not solved.

Then I said that maybe the project had a problem, and I created a new project and got the same build, but the problem was still not solved.

Then I said that maybe the problem was due to the Unity version, so I downloaded the latest version of Unity and made a build with it, but the game crashed again.

Then I said that maybe Unity couldn't build correctly, so I exported the project and built it in Android Studio. First, the apk size increased, but the game crashed again!

The project builds without errors, only when I enter the player settings and other settings; in the part that wants to load the maximum API and target, it says "getting API level..." When the API is loaded, several warnings are given in Unity! I think this could be the problem, but I haven't found any way to fix these warnings. I am posting here the screenshot of these warnings and the downloaded SDKs.
I would be grateful if someone could help me to solve this problem.

I am using Unity 2021.3.8.

[image: Warnings image]

[image: SDKs image 1]

[image: SDKs image 2]

Comment: Could it be this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72327985/unity-cvc-complex-type-2-4-a-invalid-content-was-found-starting-with-element ?
Or this : https://forum.unity.com/threads/warning-when-building-android-app-invalid-content-was-found-starting-with-element-base-extension.1266395/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fP1moOOWhrY,
It should solve your problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).